# Correct way to specify inline implicit ordering

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

Let's say I've got a case class definition:

```
// Scala 2.13
case class Employee(name: String, id: Int)
```

Then I'd like to specify an inline implicit ordering like:

```
es.sorted(implicit ord: Ordering[Employee] = Ordering.by(_.name))
```

which doesn't work.

What could be a correct way to do that?

Comment: WDYM doesn't work? What error do you get? Which **Scala** version are you using? Why did you think that would be the right syntax? - Anyways, making some assumptions, you probably just want `es.sorted(Ordering.by(_.name))` Althought, not sure why not just use `es.sortBy(_.name)`

Comment: `es.sortBy(_.name)` works indeed. The intention was to go through implicit ordering.

Comment: Do you want such ordering to be the default one of the class? Or just for this particular method?

Comment: Just for this particular instance. I'd be interested to see all  syntaxes possible

Comment: Then you can either pass it explicitly as I did in my comment and on Dmytro's answer, or you may declare the implicit value in the same scope as where the method is called. - but, really, since this situation is too common is better to use the `sortBy` method.

Comment: This is entirely for educational purpose: to see what's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify `Ordering` explicitly at a call site

```
case class Employee(name: String, id: Int)

es.sorted[Employee](Ordering.by(_.name))
// es.sorted(Ordering.by((_: Employee).name))
// es.sortBy(_.name)
```

or define default `Ordering` at the definition site (an instance of the type class `Ordering` for the data type `Employee`)

```
case class Employee(name: String, id: Int)
object Employee {
  implicit val employeeOrdering: Ordering[Employee] = Ordering.by(_.name)
}

es.sorted
```

Comment: Just wondering: why implicit ordering needs to be specified in the companion object and specifying in the class definition doesn't work?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits What you're defining in a class depends on an instance of the class (`this`). Implicit `Ordering[Employee]` is defined for the whole `class Employee`, not for its specific `this` (should be `static` in Java terminology). Another question is not why is defined but why is found. Well, that's convention. See details in the question linked.